# jQuery cookies not working !

Tags: jquery, cookies, setcookie

I have a big problem, jQuery cookies not working in all browsers..
And I'm using latest jQuery library version 1.4.4

Please help me

**Edit:**

```
var mid = $.cookie('mid');
if (mid == '1') {
    $('#something').css('background', '#d3d3d3');
}
```

Comment: "not working" is the second worse description of a problem you can possibly offer, and that's next to silence.  **What** isn't working? Always describe the behavior/error you're seeing.

Comment: the problem is the code doesn't work after i use $.cookie

Comment: @phplover - please paste a code snippet to show what is not working.

Comment: See now I putted a snippet, it's not working and the code stuck and stop working

Comment: where are you setting $.cookie('mid')'s value? you should have something like $.cookie('mid','1'); elsewhere in your code.

Comment: You are not providing any useful information. Where are you setting the cookie? Does the cookie actually get set? (Check in your browser)

Comment: yeah I'm using document.cookie because $.cookie('mid', '1'); does not work

Comment: So, if you add an alert before the `if`, you don't see it? Try checking the error console for errors (on Firefox, Ctrl+Shift+J, or F12 for firebug). Also, silly idea, make sure you the cookie plugin is included in the page properly.

Comment: FYI, if you are working on raw HTML files in your file system cookies won't work in Chrome. You've got to host the HTML files for cookies to start working. I hosted my files on my local machine in IIS by throwing them into the following folder to get cookies to work locally: C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Try checking the error console for errors (on Firefox, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, or <kbd>F12</kbd> for firebug).
2. Make sure you the [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) is included in the page properly.

Comment: Cookie plugin's link is not found.

Answer (score 9):

I had the Same Problem and the solution was too simple, I was loading jquery.cookie.js before I was loading jquery. As soon as I rearranged the script inclusions the problem went away.

```
script type="text/javascript" SRC="javascript/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
script type="text/javascript" SRC="javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
script type="text/javascript" SRC="javascript/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This might sound like a stupid question, but are you sure you have the jQuery cookie plugin included in your markup file? If it's [this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie), it doesn't come out of the box with jQuery, you have to include it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to confirm the html page is in server like localhost or hosted in any server.
If you try to implement in index.html in general local directory in your pc, it will not work.
Thanks